# No lease on /my/hdfs/file/path.json : File does not exist

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm using Spark Structured Stream to read message from Kafka, The messages contains path to zip file that include JSON files, I take the JSONs and write them to HDFS by the following code:

First, I'm createing readStream to kafka.

```java
    Dataset<Row> dsRow = spark.readStream()
                              .format("kafka")
                              .options(/*KAFKA OPTIONS - Servers etc*/)
                              .load();
```

Then, I'm create writeStream to ForeachQuery

```java
dsRow.writeStream()
     .queryName("ForEachQuery")
     .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
     .foreach(writer)
     .start()
     .awaitTermination();
```

And my writer looks like:

```java
    ForeachWriter<Row> writer = new ForeachWriter() {

             @Override
             public void process(Row arg0) {
                 //Here I'm extracting the ZIP content (JSON files) to HDFS.
             }

             @Override 
             public boolean open(long arg0, long arg1) { return true; }

             @Override 
             public void close(long arg0, long arg1) {  }

    }
```

My problem is sometimes I got the following exception:

> No lease on /user/myuser/path/filefromzip.json (inode 1815182): File
>   does not exist. Holder DFSClient_NOMAPREDUCE_1932232_180 does not have
>   any open files.

I know that's occurred because I work in parallel but how can I solve it?
Maybe it's because duplicates processing? If so, How can I prevent in on `open` method?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that you json path is a local path at some machine , which spark cannot access.

Comment: spark can access to my json path, in 95% of time its success and the json files writed to HDFS, but I got this exception every 3-5mins~